# OutOfMemory: How to release memory of ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory

Im getting the nice OutOfMemory Exception and want to know how to release memory of a ImageView. 
Dont like the bitmap recycle() because i want those images to be used again.

My Program looks like in the code below.
I have a lot of images in my @drawable folder and want to shuffle them in a single ImageView. I made this with two CountDownTimer which repeat setImageResource() after a few seconds. With only a few pictures its working fine, but if i extend the number of images i get the Exception.

**So is there a way for ImageViews to release the memory of the currently unused pictures.**

And yes i already know this page, so please dont direct me there.
[Managing Bitmap Memory](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)

Thanks for your help :)

```
private int rotateIndex;
final int NUM_OF_IMAGES = 23;

private int imageArray[] = new int[NUM_OF_IMAGES];

imageArray[0] = R.drawable.tv;
    imageArray[1] = R.drawable.background;
    imageArray[2] = R.drawable.background1;
    imageArray[3] = R.drawable.backgroundplain;
    imageArray[4] = R.drawable.myimage;
    imageArray[5] = R.drawable.myimage1;
```

.
.
.

```
countDown1 = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){

            System.out.println("timer running");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() 
    {       
            countDown2.start();
        }
    };




countDown2 = new CountDownTimer(200, 100) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

    rotateIndex =randomNumberBetween0andNUM_OF_IMAGES; // happens with a randomize method, nothing more
            rotateImage.setImageResource(imageArray[rotateIndex]);

           countDown1.start();

        }
    };

    countDown1.start();
```

Comment: try using [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) instead

Comment: u (@hrskrs) mean Handler instead of the Timers right? but how would this solve the OutOfMemory Exception?

Comment: if your images are too large you have to scale them down and show it. Otherwise if the images are not that large and giving you an `OutOfMemory` Exception, thats an issue with `Timer`. If your images are not too large than try using `Handler` otherwise refer to this [link](http://sunil-android.blogspot.com.tr/2013/08/out-of-memory-exception-during-decode.html)

Comment: @hrskrs my images arent tha large, each about 60kb which i think is small. so i might try it with the handler, thanks for the hint :) !

Comment: if that is the case, as i said, try that with `handler.` If it works or if answers are helpful to you you can upvote them. That is the way how you thank in `SO`

Comment: can you post a complete stacktrace of your OOM?

Comment: @hrskrs where can i upvote a comment? I only know it for answers...

Comment: @MaxHof hover on the comment and in the left side of the comment you will si the upvote button.